# HMAC Hex Digest generated with GitHub not matching with the digest that Java gives

Tags: java, github, sha

This is the code am using on the Java side

```
private String encodedHexString(String secretKey, String payload)
        throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, InvalidKeyException {

    SecretKeySpec keySpec = new SecretKeySpec(secretKey.getBytes(),"HmacSHA1");
    Mac mac = Mac.getInstance("HmacSHA1");
    mac.init(keySpec);

    byte[] payloadDigest = mac.doFinal(payload.getBytes());
    String encodedDigest = DatatypeConverter.printHexBinary(payloadDigest);
    return encodedDigest;
}
```

where **secretKey** is the Secret token entered on GitHub side as well on my side and the payload is what I am getting in the `request.getParameter("payload")` for `application/x-www-form-urlencoded Content-type`.

matching this with `request.getHeader("X-Hub-Signature")` don't match unfortunately, even after appending `"sha1="` to it on Java side.

Answer (score 1):

I had success with simply encoding the whole request body, without any kind of parameter parsing, unescaping, etc:

```
String secret = "73fcce1ecaeeb4136f27854eaaacb785929bb9a3";
String payload = "payload=%7B%22zen%22%3A%22It%27s+not+fully+shipped+until+it%27s+fast.%22%2C%22hook_id%2...";
System.out.println(encodedHexString(secret, payload));
```

The result was:

```
0F026F9E5107F4BF377CA032C1431BFED687B6E9
```

This matched the `X-Hub-Signature` header very well:

```
X-Hub-Signature: sha1=0f026f9e5107f4bf377ca032c1431bfed687b6e9
```

Comment: How did you retrieve the raw payload? I'm using Jetty, but all I get is the unescaped JSON string which results in a mismatching hash.

Comment: Never mind, I just realised after half a day of debugging that I had the arguments `secret` and `payload` the wrong way around... *sigh*